# Console.Write syntax: what does the format string "{0, -25}" mean

Tags: c#

I am writing C# code

```
Console.Write("{0,-25}", company);
```

In above code what does this `"{0,-25}"` thing mean?

Comment: Actually i have copied and pasted but don't get it what it does

Answer (score 10):

You mention it's hard to see what it does: that's because it adds spaces and those are difficult to see in the console. Try adding a character directly before and after the output so you can more clearly see the space, like the examples below:

This

```
Console.WriteLine("[{0, -25}]", "Microsoft"); // Left aligned 
Console.WriteLine("[{0,  25}]", "Microsoft"); // Right aligned
Console.WriteLine("[{0,   5}]", "Microsoft"); // Ignored, Microsoft is longer than 5 chars
```

Will result in this (with spaces)

```
[Microsoft                ]
[                Microsoft]
[Microsoft]
```

Which looks like this in the console window:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Read about string formatting on MSDN, specifically [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx). The '-25;' specifies the alignment component.

> **Alignment Component** The optional alignment component is a signed
>   integer indicating the preferred formatted field width. If the value
>   of alignment is less than the length of the formatted string,
>   alignment is ignored and the length of the formatted string is used as
>   the field width. The formatted data in the field is right-aligned if
>   alignment is positive and left-aligned if alignment is negative. If
>   padding is necessary, white space is used. The comma is required if
>   alignment is specified.

Answer (score 0):

That 'thing' is a composite formatting string. See the remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf.aspx) and this article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is used for alignment.
Check this so that you can get

```
Console.Write("Company = |{0,-25}|", company);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string company1="ABC Inc";
string company2="XYZ International Inc";
Console.Write("{0,-10}", company1);//o/p [ABC Inc...]
Console.Write("{0,10}", company1);o/p [...ABC Inc]
Console.Write("{0,-10}", company2);o/p [XYZ International Inc]
```

//In the first Write(),output is **LEFT justified** in an output     field width of 10

//In second Write(), output is **RIGHT** justified in an output    field width of 10

//In the third Write(), output width is ignored , since the company2 name has more than 10 characters.